# Javascript Unexpected Behaviour during Subtraction

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a javascript code like this

```
    var a=10;
    var b="100";        
    document.write(b-a);
```

Actually it should show an error when we are subtracting a number from a string but it is showing as 90 as output but when we do b+a it is showing 10010 as output what is this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you subtract, Javascript attempts to cast the String `b` to Number, because there is no `-` operation defined for String.

When you use the `+` sign, Javascript attempts to cast the Number `a` to a String, because `+` is defined as concatenation for a String.

Answer (score 4):

the `-` operator in JavaScript only applies to math, so your vars are both converted to numbers.  You'll only get an error (or more specifically `NaN`) if you try to do invalid math, e.g. `100 - 'a'`. The `+` operator is valid for both strings and numbers, so its behavior changes:

- If both vars are numbers, mathematical additions is used
- otherwise string concatenation is used